# Symfony 2 custom form field type: how to add javascript and css only once?

Tags: forms, symfony, twig

I want to use javascript in custom Symfony 2 form field type extension. So, I have Twig extension template like this:

```
{% block some_widget %}
    <input ... />

    <script src="some.js"></script>
    <link href="some.css" />
{% endblock %}
```

But I want to have these script and link tags only once in my HTML, ideally in head tag, without modifing base template. I tried to extend Twig blocks, but I have no access to action template blocks inside form template. Or maybe something like this:

```
{# widget tempate #}
{% block some_widget %}
    <input ... />

    {{ use_javascript('some.js') }}
    {{ use_css('some.css') }}
{% endblock %}

{# main action template #}
...
<head>
{{ dump_javascripts() }}
{{ dump_css() }}
</head>
...
```

How to do this with Symfony 2 Forms + Twig?

P.S. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Why don't you want to modify the base template? This *is* the place to set which js\css files you want to import

Comment: I want to create some self-containing form widget extension bundle and enable this bundle only once in AppKernel.php. Moreover I want don't include js/css if widget has no use in current page.

Comment: This seems to be a missing feature in Symfony (until now). Maybe we should inspire from [django widget media](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/media/#assets-as-a-static-definition) which includes the assets once only if the widget present

Comment: Still appears to be missing in 2021 unless there's something I'm not seeing...

Answer (score 10):

I had to write a self contained form widget that requires javascript, I was able to achieve what you are trying to do through the `event_dispatcher` listening on the `kernel.response` to append the javascript at the end of the `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response`. Here's a snippet of my form type :

```
<?php

namespace AcmeBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcherInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;

class AcmeFileType extends AbstractType{

  private $twig;
  private $dispatcher;

  public function __construct(\Twig_Environment $twig, EventDispatcherInterface $dispatcher){
    $this->twig = $twig;
    $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
  }

  public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options){

    $javascriptContent = $this->twig->render('AcmeBundle:Form:AcmeFileType.js.twig', array());

    $this->dispatcher->addListener('kernel.response', function($event) use ($javascriptContent) {

      $response = $event->getResponse();
      $content = $response->getContent();
      // finding position of </body> tag to add content before the end of the tag
      $pos = strripos($content, '</body>');
      $content = substr($content, 0, $pos).$javascriptContent.substr($content, $pos);

      $response->setContent($content);
      $event->setResponse($response);
    });

  }

  ...
```

When you define your form type in your services.yml it looks like this :

```
acme.form.acme_file_type:
    class: AcmeBundle\Form\AcmeFileType
    arguments:
        - @twig
        - @event_dispatcher
    tags:
        - { name: form.type, alias: acmefile }
```

So now, everytime you build a form with `acmefile` the javascript will be appended to the `<body>`. This solution **does not prevent** the javascript from being **present multiple time** though, but you should easily be able to improve this to suit your needs.

You can also play around with the `$response` object to modify the **headers** instead if you wish.

Comment: Seems legit. Symfony uses a similar trick to load the web debug toolbar.

Comment: You should prepend `if (!$event->isMasterRequest()) return;` to the `kernel.response` listener in order to avoid adding this snippet to every single subrequest/-response.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is to provide the separate template with css & scripts loading.
With the comments in readme so only thing developer will must do is to

```
{% block stylesheets %}
  {{ parent() }}

  include "@MyBestBundle/Resources/view/styles.html.twig"

{% endblock %}
```

or try to intercept the form rendering with DI and add the assets. But it more difficult to do , if possible to implement.

Answer (score 1):

My way of doing was by creating a custom twig extension where I add JS to a buffer and during form rendering and later dump it at the of my layout.

Something like this:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Twig;

use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class WysiwygExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    /**
     * @var array
     *
     * A pool of elements IDs for Wysiwyg binding.
     */
    private $wysiwygElements = [];

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getFunctions()
    {
        return array(
            new TwigFunction('addWysiwygBinding', [$this, 'addWysiwygBinding']),
            new TwigFunction('popWysiwygBindings', [$this, 'popWysiwygBindings']),
        );
    }

    public function addWysiwygBinding(string $id): void
    {
        $this->wysiwyglements[] = $id;
    }

    public function popWysiwygBindings(): array
    {
        $elements = array_unique($this->wysiwygElements);

        $this->wysiwygElements = [];

        return $elements;
    }
}
```

Then `form-fields.html.twig`:

```
...
{% block wysiwyg_widget %}
{% apply spaceless %}
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    {% do addWysiwygBinding(id) %}
{% endapply %}
{% endblock %}
...
```

Then `layout.html.twig`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...

        {% set ids = popWysiwygBindings() %}

        {% if ids is not empty %}
            {% javascripts
                'bundles/admin/plugins/wysiwyg_1.js'
                'bundles/admin/plugins/wysiwyg_2.js'
            %}
                <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
            {% endjavascripts %}
        {% endif %}

        {% for id in ids %}
            {{ include('_wysiwyg.html.twig', { id: id }) }}
        {% endfor %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I use it. Hope it's what you're looking for.

base.html.twig

```
<head>
   {% block stylesheets %}
       css...
   {% endblock %}
</head>
```

foo.html.twig

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block stylesheets %}
   {{ parent() }}

   css that you need in foo.html.twig

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Yes, this is usual way for regular view tempates (and I use it). But this don't work with form type templates.

Answer (score 0):

I found some 'dirty' method used by many peoples in other situations.
We check the loading of script on client side. In case we have a zlkladr.js file, that have a global object 'zlkladr'

```
{% block our_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
  ...
  <script>
    // We must load the script only once, even if many widgets on form
    if ( !window.zlkladr ) {
      document.write('<script src="{{ asset('bundles/kladr/js/zlkladr.js') }}"></sc'+'ript>');
    }
  </script>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock %}
```